# How do I extract numbers from a string in Python?

Tags: python, regex

I would like to extract numbers from an input string in Python.

For example, If the input string is:

```
CS9ED389^329IP"~a48#
```

Expected Output is:

```
[9, 389, 329, 48]
```

I did try this, but didn't work:

```
val = "CS9ED389^329IP~a48#"

result = re.findall("\d+", val)
```

Comment: [Your current code is working](https://rextester.com/KBVO91063).  Voting to close as a typo question.

Comment: Voting to close due to typo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You regexp is correct beside missing `r` also if you need exactly numbers you just need to cast them to `int`:

```
numbers = [int(number) for number in re.findall(r"\d+", val)]
print(numbers) # list of numbers
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use nums_from_string. You have to install it: pip install nums-from-string

```
import nums_from_string

line = "CS9ED389^329IP~a48#"

result = nums_from_string.get_nums(line)
print(result)
```

Output:
[9, 389, 329, 48]